Can't see network tab when trying to debug a shared worker on firefox for developers
As you can see in this, image, network dev tool is disabled, can't see network data coming to this shared worker

I went to this address -- > about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox, went to my shared worker and selected Inspect

I tried reloading the script that creates the shared worker.

There is an open issue on the Bugzilla issue tracker exactly about this issue.
According to the comments, Chrome could be a solution to debug Websocket requests in a SharedWorker (chrome://inspect/#workers).
